# Why, in git aliases, can $0 be the invoked program or the first positional parameter?

Tags: git

When I use `$0` in a git alias, it has two different behaviors:

- it has the value of the parameter passed, if any
- if no parameters are passed, it is the shell name

For example:

```
test = "!sh -c 'echo $0'"

$ git test abc # prints `abc`
$ git test     # prints `sh`
```

I'm aware that I can define a function (and use `$1`), but I was wondering what the reason for this behavior is.

I've ["RTFM"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases), but there isn't any reference to positional parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Less to do with Git, more to do with the shell, which expects the first argument you pass to be `$0`:

```
$ sh -c 'echo $0'
sh

$ sh -c 'echo $0' hey
hey
```

The right way to write `test` like that would be

```
test = "!sh -c 'echo $1' sh"
```